# Erro: "cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**"

Tags: c++

Estou tentando mandar o endereço de uma matriz para uma função criada (que tem como parâmetro um ponteiro que também é uma matriz). O erro é o seguinte:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> main.cpp:30:28: error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'int**' for argument '1' to 'int somadiferenca(int**)'
>    somadiferenca(&numaboa[2]);    
> exit status 1
> ```

Estou compilando com o repl.it, mas o erro é basicamente o mesmo ao compilar em outro lugar.

O código é o seguinte:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int somadiferenca(int *vetor[2])
{        
    int x;
    int y;

    x = (*vetor[0]) + (*vetor[1]);
    y = (*vetor[0]) - (*vetor[1]);

    if(y<0)
    {                
        y = -y;
        cout << x << endl << y;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << x << endl << y;
    }    
}
int main()
{
   int numaboa[2];

   cin >> numaboa[0];
   cin >> numaboa[1];

   somadiferenca(&numaboa[2]);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Achei muito confuso sua organização de código. Creio que o argumento de `somadiferenca` deva ser só um vetor de duas posições, passando como parâmetro a variável `numaboa`

Comment: A idéia era testar o uso de pointers juntamente com  arrays , mas não deu certo. Quero entender por quê não deu certo com o ponteiro, mas conseguiria fazer sem ele facilmente. Valeu pela resposta, Jefferson ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miguel, acontece que `&numaboa[2]` é o endereço da célula de índice `2`. Quer dizer, `&numaboa[0]` dá no mesmo que `numaboa` (endereço da primeira célula), `&numaboa[1]` dá no mesmo que `numaboa+1` (endereço da segunda célula) e `&numaboa[2]` dá no mesmo que `numaboa+2` (ou seja, aponta para uma célula que nem existe).

Além disso, o parâmetro `int v[]` indica que `v` é um ponteiro porque o símbolo de array (ou vetor) é tratado como um ponteiro constante que vale o endereço da primeira célula, ou seja, o parâmetro `int *vetor[2]` indica que `vetor` é um tipo ponteiro para outro ponteiro, este para inteiro.

Sendo assim, saiba que se a intenção é utilizar os valores das células então você pode passar `numaboa` como argumento num parâmetro de tipo `int*` (ou seja, função pode ser `void somadiferenca( int *vetor )` ou `void somadiferenca( int vetor[] )` ou `void somadiferenca( int vetor[2] )`) e então acessar as duas células usando `vetor[0]` e  `vetor[1]`.

Uma forma válida de implementar tudo é a seguinte, que `somadiferenca` aceita ponteiro, o `somadiferenca(numaboa)` de fato faz passagem de ponteiro e dentro da função faz o acesso das células via parâmetro tipo ponteiro.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int somadiferenca( int *vetor ){        
    int x = vetor[0] + vetor[1] ;
    int y = vetor[0] - vetor[1] ;
    if( y<0 ){       
        cout << x << endl << (-y) ;
    }
    else {
        cout << x << endl << y;
    }    
}

int main(){
   int numaboa[2] ;
   cin >> numaboa[0] ;
   cin >> numaboa[1] ;
   somadiferenca( numaboa ) ;
   return 0 ;
}
```

Lembrando algumas coisas básica:

1) `int numaboa[2]` é a definição de duas células locais temporárias na função que são alocadas consecutivamente na memória (pilha de execução);

2) `numaboa` é o ponteiro constante (inalterável) que sempre aponta para essas duas células (`numaboa` vale o endereço da primeira, via índice se endereça outras) vendo-as como array;

3) `numaboa[i]` é uma célula do array e `numaboa+i` é o mesmo que `&(numaboa[i])`, ou seja, o endereço da célula `numaboa[i]`;

4) Parâmetros `int vector[]` e `int *vector` são a mesma coisa, ambos ponteiros, afinal símbolos de arrays como `vetor` alocados na pilha são tratados como ponteiros.

Ok?
Alguma dúvida?

Comment: MUITO BOM!!!!!!!! NENHUMA DÚVIDA!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Que tal:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void somadiferenca( int vetor[2] )
{
    int x = vetor[0] + vetor[1];
    int y = vetor[0] - vetor[1];

    if( y < 0 )
        y = -y;

    cout << "Soma: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Diferenca: " << y << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int numaboa[2];

    cout << "a: ";
    cin >> numaboa[0];

    cout << "b: ";
    cin >> numaboa[1];

    somadiferenca( numaboa );

    return 0;
}
```

Ou:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void somadiferenca( int * vetor )
{
    int x = *vetor + *(vetor+1);
    int y = *vetor - *(vetor+1);

    if( y < 0 )
        y = -y;

    cout << "Soma: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Diferenca: " << y << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int numaboa[2];

    cout << "a: ";
    cin >> numaboa[0];

    cout << "b: ";
    cin >> numaboa[1];

    somadiferenca( &numaboa[0] );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cara, valeu por responder!!! :) Desse jeito aí eu sei que funciona. É que, teoricamente, nesse caso, a utilização dos ponteiros meio que otimizaria o tamanho e tempo de execução do programa. Tipo, na função somadiferenca você criou variáveis, que de certa forma você nem vai usar (só servem pra definir como a função vai se comportar). Daí no main você criou outras variáveis, que teoricamente serão copiadas para dentro da void somadiferenca (isso já toma tempo e espaço) para ela fazer o que tem que fazer. Só aí diversas variáveis foram criadas inutilmente. Me corrijammmm , sou novo nisso de C++

Comment: Com os ponteiros (claro, o ponteiro ocupa o espaço do tipo da variável no qual ele é definido), você só dá o endereço das variáveis que você criou na main e ele usa elas mesmo. Assim, para não criar variáveis na void que nem seriam usadas , criei os ponteiros , para que pudessem apenas redirecionar para as variáveis da main e fazerem o que tem que ser feito. Sou novo nisso de C++, me corrijam caso o meu raciocínio esteja errado.  :)

Comment: Agora que eu ví que tu fez uma com ponteiro!!!!! Valeuuu, acho que entendi o por que do meu código não ter dado certo!!!!!